# Get rid of padding for UITableViewCell custom accessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view cell with a custom `accessoryView`, but it seems that the way it's laid out by default creates a 15-point margin on the right side. I want to get rid of it.

I can achieve the desired effect by overriding `layoutSubviews`, but that breaks edit mode animation (the accessory no longer slides in/out).

Any better way to do this?

Comment: Add the custom accessory view to cell's contenView instead of adding in accessoryView. You can set the frame for that anywhere in cell's contentView.

Comment: @sanjaymathad Then I don't have an accessory, and hence it won't animate when I edit the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add subview instead of accessoryView

```
UIButton *deleteBtn = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteBtn.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width-55, 2, 50, 50);
[deleteBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"] 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
deleteBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//deleteBtn.alpha = 0.5;
deleteBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(numberDeleteConfirm:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.contentView addSubview:deleteBtn];
```